# Conditional Running Count in Pandas for All Previous Rows Only

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C'], 
                    'Date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-02-15', 
                             '2019-03-15', '2019-04-05', '2019-04-05', '2019-04-15', '2019-06-10'],
                    'Sale':[100,200,150,200,150,100,300,250,500,400]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df

Event         Date
    A   2019-01-01
    B   2019-02-01
    A   2019-03-01
    A   2019-03-01
    B   2019-02-15
    C   2019-03-15
    B   2019-04-05
    B   2019-04-05
    A   2019-04-15
    C   2019-06-10
```

I would like to obtain the following result:

```
Event         Date  Previous_Event_Count
    A   2019-01-01                     0
    B   2019-02-01                     0
    A   2019-03-01                     1
    A   2019-03-01                     1
    B   2019-02-15                     1
    C   2019-03-15                     0
    B   2019-04-05                     2
    B   2019-04-05                     2
    A   2019-04-15                     3
    C   2019-06-10                     1
```

where `df['Previous_Event_Count']` is the number of an event (rows) when the event (`df['Event']`) takes place before its adjacent date (`df['Date']`). For instance,

- The number of event A takes place before 2019-01-01 is 0,
- The number of event A takes place before 2019-03-01 is 1, and
- The number of event A takes place before 2019-04-15 is 3.

I am able to obtain the desired result using this line:

```
df['Previous_Event_Count'] = [df.loc[(df.loc[i, 'Event'] == df['Event']) & (df.loc[i, 'Date'] > df['Date']), 
                                     'Date'].count() for i in range(len(df))]
```

Although, it is slow but it works fine. I believe there is a better way to do that. I have tried this line:

```
df['Previous_Event_Count'] = df.query('Date < Date').groupby(['Event', 'Date']).cumcount()
```

but it produces NaNs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `groupby` + [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html)

Dates can be treated as numeric. Use`'min'` to get your counting logic.

```
df['PEC'] = (df.groupby('Event').Date.rank(method='min')-1).astype(int)

  Event       Date  PEC
0     A 2019-01-01    0
1     B 2019-02-01    0
2     A 2019-03-01    1
3     A 2019-03-01    1
4     B 2019-02-15    1
5     C 2019-03-15    0
6     B 2019-04-05    2
7     B 2019-04-05    2
8     A 2019-04-15    3
9     C 2019-06-10    1
```

Comment: Ah, very clever! I was wondering, is there any way we could use something like `query` or `transform`? +1

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 I can't really think of such a way that wouldn't involve looping, perhaps someone else will know. I think it can be done with a merge, but that's likely slower and many more lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

First get counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) per both columns, then aggregate by first level with `shift` and cumulative sum and last `join` to original:

```
s = (df.groupby(['Event', 'Date'])
       .size()
       .groupby(level=0)
       .apply(lambda x: x.shift(1).cumsum())
       .fillna(0)
       .astype(int))

df = df.join(s.rename('Previous_Event_Count'), on=['Event','Date'])
print (df)
  Event       Date  Previous_Event_Count
0     A 2019-01-01                     0
1     B 2019-02-01                     0
2     A 2019-03-01                     1
3     A 2019-03-01                     1
4     B 2019-02-15                     1
5     C 2019-03-15                     0
6     B 2019-04-05                     2
7     B 2019-04-05                     2
8     A 2019-04-15                     3
9     C 2019-06-10                     1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. An idea suddenly flashed through my mind and it turned out it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I can find a better and faster way to get the desired result. It turns out that it is very easy. One can try:

```
df['Total_Previous_Sale'] = df.groupby('Event').cumcount() \
                          - df.groupby(['Event', 'Date']).cumcount()
```